# Postgresql Conditional in where clause

Tags: postgresql, where-clause

I'm using postgres and I want to do a conditional in the where clause.

I want to filter on date1, but if date1 is null, then I want to filter on date2. I tried to following, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
WHERE
(date1 BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31')
OR (CASE WHEN date1 is null THEN date2 BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31')
```

Comment: `WHERE COALESCE(date1, date2) BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'` (coalesce returns the first non-null value)